# On the order of matrix groups.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I have two subgroups $A,B$ of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A \subset B$ and $[B:A]$ is finite. Then you can define the subgroups $A^1=\{a \in A: \det a =1\}$ and $B^1=\{b\in B: \det b =1\}$. Do we always have that $[B^1:A^1]$ is finite?

The problem I am trying to prove is that for any two orders $O,O'$ in a quaternion algebra $B$ over the rationals (or maybe even number fields) I want $\Gamma^1(O)$ and $\Gamma^1(O')$ to be commensurable. Here $\Gamma^1(O)$ is defined as the embedding of the units with norm $1$ into $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ as a group under multiplication, and then we mod out by $\{\pm 1\}$.

If we let $N:=\{\det b : b\in B\}$ and define for $n\in N$ that $B_n:=\{b\in B: \det b=n\}$ then we have a bijection between all pairs $B_n,B_{n'}$ for $n,n'\in N$ so I feel like $[B^1:A^1]\leq [B:A]$ should be true, but I am not sure about the details. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you recall exactly how you define notation $[B^1:A^1]=[B \cap SL_2 : A \cap SL_2]$ ?

Comment: Maybe you can find indications in the SL2(R) book by Serge Lang ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I see $A^1$ and $B^1$ as groups under multiplication, so the I define that index to be the index as groups.

Answer (score 5):

In general, if $H$, $A \subseteq B$ are subgroups of $G$, then $|B \cap H:A \cap H| \leq |B:A|$. Define the map $f$: {cosets of $A \cap H$ in $B \cap H$} $\rightarrow$ {cosets of $A$ in $B$} by $f(x(A \cap H))=xA$. Show that $f$ is well-defined and injective. In your case $H=SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.